# Bad resolution on second monitor Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, xorg, multi-monitor

I have a 32" TV and I want to use it as a secondary monitor.

I've been following [this guide](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8301/how-do-i-change-my-monitors-resolution/) on how to change the resolution using xorg.conf.

I created three files inside `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`:

`40-monitor.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "VGA1"
  Option      "PreferredMode" "1408x792"
EndSection
```

`30-graphic.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Intel Integrated"
    Driver          "intel"
EndSection
```

`50-screen.conf`:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth          24
            Modes         "1408x792"  "1024x768"   "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**It does not work**.

[image: It offers me the resolution 1408x792]

I tried to apply the resolution but doesn't work. The TV tells me the resolution it's using is 1024x768.

PS. The resolution that I want is `1408x792`.

PS2. I configured this months ago but unfortunately lost everything on the hard drive and had to install Fedora 24 from zero today and I don't remember what my `xorg.conf` looked like. :(

Please, let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

I updated `~/.config/monitors.xml` and looked for `VGA1` which is my TV and set up correct `width` and `height` (1408x792) and after a restart the configuration was applied successfully.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my case when i first time using extended monitor with Fedora 25, here how i solve this problem.

**First** check your gnome session, is it using Wayland or Xorg, you can check it by executing this command

```
xrandr -q
```

If it showing your monitor device like `Xwayland0` or `Xwayland1` you should change to use Xorg.

**Second**, change your session to use xorg if you're using wayland by edit file at

```
/etc/gdm/custom.conf
```

Then uncomment line on `WaylandEnable=false` to disable it

```
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
#Enable=true
```

**Third** restart your machine to take effect

**Fourth** check your display resolution by running command `xrandr -q` again, there would be a different information for each device like this

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3046 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      60.10*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

the information above is from mine (it ca be different than yours, just for example)

**Fifth** as you can see I have no `VGA1` resolution bigger than `1024x768`, but I need to set my monitor which is connected on `VGA1` to have a resolution at `1680x1050`, here the tricks

**Six** Create your own display resolution by using [cvt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cvt), in this case I want to add resolution `1680x1050`

```
cvt 1680 1050
```

cvt will produce info like

```
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

then for the next step is creating our resolution mode, based on that info

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1680x1050_60.00"
```

as you can see, two commands above will creatie new mode by assign `--newmode` with display resolution `1680x1050_60.00`, and add that resolution mode by using `--addmode` into my connected monitor on `VGA1` (make sure your monitor is connected, check with `xrandr -q`)

Then for the **Last Step**, we apply that resolution into our monitor which is in this example is `VGA1` by executing this command

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1680x1050_60.00
```

If all step was correct, your monitor display now should be on selected display, you may check it too by running command `xrandr -q`, and because this instruction is based on my experience, pardon me if this method is still not helpful for you.

***tips**
**If you have a case like when your monitor is just flickering after you set output or add the mode, first backup file on `~/.config/monitors.xml` then delete it**